# Proper way to process forms

Tags: http

What is proper way to process forms in http?

on /somepage:

```
<form method="POST" action="/someaction.html">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Let's assume, that user didn't filled in "name". So I should produce some error. How should I do it:

**First method**

1. POST /someaction and 302 Redirect to /posterror?error=1
2. GET /posterror?error=1 and 200 Ok with content about errors and form

**Second**

1. POST /someaction and 200 Ok with content about errors and form

**Third**

1. POST /someaction, remember in session form errors and 302 Redirect to /posterror
2. GET /posterror and 200 Ok with content about errors and form

Which one is proper way? Maybe some fourth one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach is called [post/redirect/get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and is described by wikipedia as:

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a common design pattern for web developers
>   to help avoid certain duplicate form submissions and allow user agents
>   to behave more intuitively with bookmarks and the refresh button.

Comment: Thanks. And what about proper GET request. Error params in URL query or in session? GET the page with form or with error? What is your opinion?

Comment: I would normally use flashdata (session data that only lasts for one page refresh) to show an error at the top of the form. If the page is refreshed the error goes away but if the form is submitted again the errors will reappear if necessary or go away (and the user redirected) if they're all fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The third one. It allows the user to safely hit refresh or bookmark the page. The first one, although similar, would require you to pass the content of form back and forth over the wire, which is inefficient. As slight refinements, you might consider:

- Redirect back to the form, not to a separate error page, to give the user a chance to correct their error
- Rather than just storing the error data in the session, store it with some unique id, and then include that in the redirect url. That way the user can can have the page open in two browser windows and they won't tread one each other's toes.
- Expire the stored error after a set length of time, or when the form is finally correctly submitted.

Comment: Store the data in session or include in URL query - that is an important question for me. I think, that storing error code in URL may be bad idea - security issues and user can bookmark form with error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having some sort of validation before the for is sent using javascript. 
Then of course you should validate the form input on the server side as well. As for whether to use redirects, I don't know of any de facto standard there.

If you want to follow use the HTTP protocol as it was meant you should probably send a 4xx status code back (e.g. 400 bad request) with an informative message saying what was wrong in the input.

Comment: "_400 Bad Request - The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax_" - don't think that 400 is appropriate status.

Answer (score 0):

Is utilizing client-side validation out of the equation? Using javascript you can avoid posting the form (and reduce server-side processing) and let the client (user's end: browser) perform the validation. What other validations do you have in mind?

Here's a link to basic validation that you can apply using javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: Client-side validation can be a convenience for the user, but absolutely cannot be trusted. The user can send any HTTP request they like; nothing forces them to run the JS you supply with the form page.